# Update and copy column of Sharepoint list from a different department

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have two lists from different departments. I'd like to copy and update changes from list A in department A to List B in department B. I use sharepoint 2013, and workflow 2010.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean different site collections by “*department*”? The default SharePoint Designer workflow does not look up across site collections since the credential works on a site level.

You can take a look at [Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=SPDActivities) that allows you to extend the lookup to a different site collection.

In addition, if you are open with SharePoint 2013 workflow, there is a Call HTTP Web Service action you can use for further development.

See a few references here:

[Copy and update list items based on changes in another list on another site.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/79c4570d-8b37-48f1-b11c-97800b8349ba/copy-and-update-list-items-based-on-changes-in-another-list-on-another-site?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

[SharePoint Workflow - Update Item in a different Site Collection.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/61837ba1-05e0-41d9-b282-4fc45ec3a8ea/sharepoint-workflow-update-item-in-a-different-site-collection?forum=sharepointdevelopment)